# Specification object doesn't contain any criteria even after creating it

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Facing issue when creating the Specification for dynamic search in Spring Data JPA.

When I pass *source-destination* or *dispatchNumber* values to below implemented Specification, the returned Specification object does not contain any criteria (refer [debug snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSvA5.png)). However, *party* and *fromDate-toDate* specification work as expected. I've referred multiple sources to identify what could be the cause but was not able to. What am I missing or doing wrong?

1. Repository

```
@Repository("tripRepository")
public interface TripRepository extends JpaRepository<Trip, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Trip> {
}
```

2. Service implementation

```
@Service
public class TripServiceImpl implements TripService {

    @Autowired
    TripRepository repository;
    
    /*other methods*/
    
    @Override
    public List<Trip> searchTrips(LocalDate fromDate, LocalDate toDate, Location source, Location destination,
                                  Party party, String dispatchNumber, Vehicle vehicle) {

        Specification<Trip> tripSpecification = TripSearchSpecification.noFilter();

        if (fromDate != null && toDate != null && toDate.isAfter(fromDate)) {
            tripSpecification = tripSpecification.and(TripSearchSpecification.searchByFromDateToDate(fromDate, toDate));
        }
        if (party.getParty_id() != 0) {
            tripSpecification = tripSpecification.and(TripSearchSpecification.searchByParty(party));
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(dispatchNumber)) {
            tripSpecification.and(TripSearchSpecification.searchByDispatchNumber(dispatchNumber));
        }
        if (source.getLocation_id() != 0 && destination.getLocation_id() != 0) {
            tripSpecification.and(TripSearchSpecification.searchBySourceDestination(source, destination));
        }
        final List<Trip> tripList = repository.findAll(tripSpecification);
        return tripList;
    }
}
```

3. Controller

```
@Controller
public class TripController {
    
    @Autowired
    TripService tripService;
    
    /*other methods*/
    
    @GetMapping("/trip/search")
    public String searchTrips(@ModelAttribute("searchTrip") Trip filter,
                              @RequestParam(required = false, value = "fromDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") LocalDate fromDate,
                              @RequestParam(required = false, value = "toDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") LocalDate toDate,
                              RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletRequest request) {

        List<Trip> trips = tripService.searchTrips(fromDate, toDate, filter.getSource(), filter.getDestination(),
                filter.getParty(), filter.getDispatchNumber(), filter.getVehicle());
                
        if (!trips.isEmpty()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("tripList", trips);
        } else {
            String message = messageSource.getMessage("search.output.failure", new String[]{null},
                    request.getLocale());
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", message);
        }
        return "redirect:/trip";
    }
}
```

4. Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trip")
public class Trip {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "trip_id")
    private int tripId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "party_id")
    private Party party;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Column(name = "trip_date")
    private LocalDate tripDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "src_id")
    private Location source;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dest_id")
    private Location destination;

    @Column(name = "dispatch_no")
    private String dispatchNumber;

    /*few other fields*/
    /*default and parameterized constructor*/
    /*getters and setters*/
}
```

5. Specification

```
public final class TripSearchSpecification {

    private TripSearchSpecification() { }

    public static Specification<Trip> noFilter() {
        return Specification.where(null);
    }

    public static Specification<Trip> searchByFromDateToDate(LocalDate fromDate, LocalDate toDate) {
        return new Specification<Trip>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Trip> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
                predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("tripDate"),fromDate));
                predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("tripDate"),toDate));
                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
            }
        };
    }

    public static Specification<Trip> searchByParty(Party party) {
        return new Specification<Trip>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Trip> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("party"), party);
            }
        };
    }

    public static Specification<Trip> searchByDispatchNumber(String dispatchNumber) {
        return new Specification<Trip>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Trip> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("dispatchNumber"), dispatchNumber);
            }
        };
    }

    public static Specification<Trip> searchBySourceDestination(Location source, Location destination) {
        return new Specification<Trip>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Trip> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
                predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("source"),source));
                predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("destination"),destination));
                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: In last if-statements (`TripServiceImpl#searchTrips`) instead of `tripSpecification.and(anotherSpecification)` have to be `tripSpecification = tripSpecification.and(anotherSpecification)`

Comment: thanks alex for pointing out such a silly mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spring-dynamic-jpa](https://github.com/joutvhu/spring-dynamic-jpa) to implement dynamic search by writing a query template.

The query template will be built into different query strings before execution depending on your parameters when you invoke the method.